# Get parent function

Tags: python

Is there a way to find what function called the current function? So for example:

```
def first():
    second()

def second():
    # print out here what function called this one
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @MikeG.: Wanting this information in a production release is bad, yes. Using it to debug and understand a large piece of Python is fine, IMHO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import inspect

def first():
    return second()

def second():
    return inspect.getouterframes( inspect.currentframe() )[1]

first()[3] # 'first'
```

Answer (score 6):

These work well for quickly adding minimal where-am-I debugging aids when you don't want to import yet another module. (CPython only, for debugging only.)

```
def LINE( back = 0 ):
    return sys._getframe( back + 1 ).f_lineno
def FILE( back = 0 ):
    return sys._getframe( back + 1 ).f_code.co_filename
def FUNC( back = 0):
    return sys._getframe( back + 1 ).f_code.co_name
def WHERE( back = 0 ):
    frame = sys._getframe( back + 1 )
    return "%s/%s %s()" % ( os.path.basename( frame.f_code.co_filename ),
                            frame.f_lineno, frame.f_code.co_name )
```

Example:

```
import sys, os # these you almost always have...

def WHERE( back = 0 ):
    frame = sys._getframe( back + 1 )
    return "%s/%s %s()" % ( os.path.basename( frame.f_code.co_filename ),
                        frame.f_lineno, frame.f_code.co_name )

def first():
    second()

def second():
    print WHERE()
    print WHERE(1)

first()
```

Output:

```
$ python fs.py
fs.py/12 second()
fs.py/9 first()
```

Comment: Is there any way to check if it is deep enough before the call, when I call `WHERE(1)` from the top parent function I get get following error: `ValueError: call stack is not deep enough
`

Comment: Thanks, I put it in a loop and successfully retrieved a problematic function in one of my scripts ! Here's a gist:  https://gist.github.com/corentinbettiol/61a2fb3b38240a1cec744f4cc95879e1

Answer (score 3):

You can use the traceback module's [extract_stack](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_stack) function.

```
import traceback
def first():
    second()

def second():
    print traceback.extract_stack(limit=2)[-2][2]
```

Answer (score 2):

The [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#module-inspect) module allows for many forms of introspection including this one, but note that it's only recommended to use such information for purposes such as debugging, not as part of your production code's functionality.  See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#the-interpreter-stack) for all details.