# Can we figure out which function call my target function in python?

Tags: python

I was wondering if maybe we could figure out which functions call another specific function?

For example,

```
def f1(): print 1 

def f2(): f1()
```

When we execute this script

```
>>> f2()
1
```

We should know `f2` call my target `f1`. Is that possible?

Comment: You can pass in the invoker function as an argument to the function.
Something like: 
    def f2(f2)

Comment: Why do you need to know this? If the function needs to behave differently, there should be a parameter that tells it what to do, it shouldn't figure it out from which function called it.

Comment: try this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529859/get-parent-function Hopefuly it will be helpful!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the caller function name inside another function in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900392/getting-the-caller-function-name-inside-another-function-in-python)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1349359/5417164

Answer (score 0):

[inspect.getframeinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getframeinfo) and other related functions in inspect can help:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def f1(): f2()
... 
>>> def f2():
...   curframe = inspect.currentframe()
...   calframe = inspect.getouterframes(curframe, 2)
...   print 'caller name:', calframe[1][3]
... 
>>> f1()
caller name: f1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want to do is to do a stack trace. This is possible by calling

```
traceback.print_exc()
```

Where you of course need to import traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use module `traceback`

```
def f():
    pass
    import traceback
    traceback.print_stack()
    print "Still working just fine"
    pass

def caller():
    f()

caller()
```

yields

```
  File "traceback.py", line 12, in <module>
    caller()
  File "traceback.py", line 9, in caller
    f()
  File "traceback.py", line 4, in f
    traceback.print_stack()
makarchuk@makarchuk:~/Workspace$ python2 traceback.py 
  File "traceback.py", line 13, in <module>
    caller()
  File "traceback.py", line 10, in caller
    f()
  File "traceback.py", line 4, in f
    traceback.print_stack()
Still working just fine
```